# How to render the following sentence with a proper emphatic construction into German?

Tags: word-order

Could this sentence ''I didn't **buy** this book, but **borrowed** it'' be rendered as follows:
*nicht kaufte ich das Buch; aber ich borgte es*
I am particularly unsure how to render **not buy** and **borrow** *emphatically*.

I suppose such emphatic effect could be achieved by special sentence word-order, mainly via re-positing *nicht* and *aber* from their usual positions as in this normal construction '*ich kaufte das Buch nicht; aber ich borgte es*'.

Could any one help with this?
Surely, alternative constructions with other emphatic devices than word-order is as much welcomed!

Comment: Sometimes you can find your original German construct in poems and literature. But then, it looks more like *Nicht kaufte ich das Buch, ich borgte es*. **This construct should NOT be used in day to day life.** It is only used in literature from the 19th century and before and in poems. Nowhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Present perfect sounds more natural than preterite here:

> Ich habe das Buch nicht gekauft, aber (*or* sondern) geliehen.
>
> Ich habe das Buch geliehen, nicht gekauft.

Moving the *finite verb* to first position is impossible, but in present perfect, we can at least move the *participle* to first position.
This kind of construction is used very infrequently, though,
and the regular word order above is already sufficiently emphatic.

> Gekauft habe ich das Buch nicht, aber (*or* sondern) geliehen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think ,,sondern'', the conjunction you used, is more appropriate than ,,aber'', which I used in the question. Besides, is ,,borgen'' appropriate in this context? (you used ,,leihen'' instead.)

Comment: I recomment using "sondern", and most definitely not "aber" in your examples, especially since the OP is interesten in emphasizing the difference. so "nicht... sondern" would be the construction of choice.

Comment: @Burki It depends on the context, and I assume that the OP described an abstract example, rather than a concrete problem. E.g., I'd use "sondern" in "Ich habe das Buch nicht gestohlen, sondern gefunden", but I'd use "aber" in "Ich habe das Buch nicht gelesen, aber durchgeblättert".

Comment: @Lynnyo There may be regional differences, but at least for me, "leihen" is much more common than "borgen".

Comment: @Uwe : I agree that Present perfect indeed facilitates emphatic expression in this case; yet I am wondering whether it is possible to put the sentence in Preterite with the same emphatic effect?

Comment: @Lynnyo: (1) In spoken language, preterite is not idiomatic in this context. (2) In present tense and preterite, you could use "tun" as an auxiliary verb and move the infinitive of the verb to first position, but that's a construction that is pretty much limited to the spoken language (and often considered as bad style), and as I said already, in spoken language, we wouldn't use preterite anyhow. (3) The regular word order is sufficiently emphatic. If you really, really need something stronger, add an exclamation mark.

Comment: Actually, I don’t find »Ich hab das Buch nicht gekauft, sondern geliehen« emphatic at all. If I had to say it twice, I would have used the participle-first construction the second time to convey more emphasis …

Comment: @Jan Whether or not the sentence is emphatic depends on how you stress the words; but of course, in the spoken language you *can* always stress the words you want to emphasize.